# Can Intellij Idea create javadoc comments for all the methods of a class at one time?

Tags: intellij-idea

I know if I type /** at the top of a method, it will create the bare bones comment for that method, is there a way to do it for a whole class at one time?  I tried the code menu, but did not see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this feature is very intentionally not implemented. JavaDoc comments that do not contain any meaningful information are useless, and auto-generating meaningful comments is impossible.

Comment: it would be a time saver over having to do /** each time.  I am adding docs to a library that has none, but I still have to go to each line and add comments as you say.

Comment: I don't think that navigating to the exact place in a pregenerated doc comment where you need to start typing is actually any faster than typing /** to start a new doc comment.

Comment: Sorry for the necromancy, but yes it absolutely is. You probably haven't been a software engineer for very long if you haven't known the joy of repeating the same few keystrokes hundreds if not thousands of times.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly quicker way is to set the action **Fix doc comment** to something like  `Alt`+`Shift`+`J` (by default there is no keyboard shortcut). Now if the cursor is anywhere in the method you can use this and it will generate the comments instead of having to be at the exact line.

There may not be a default keystroke setup for this, so you can add it.  Go to IntelliJ preferences and type 'fix doc comment' into the search bar.

[image: InteliJ Keymap Editor]

Comment: That did not work on a mac, so I had to add the shortcut manually.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it to clarify that you have to set the shortcut up yourself to use.